# error hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a com component. Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

I try to add a list view to view.ascx file. The got an error in the design view "error hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a com component". What happen?

Comment: you mention "design view" - is this in the IDE during development, then? or at runtime in the app?

Comment: in the IDE during development